# Css 'elem > elem' selector not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the page of a [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKNxeF4KMsY) in youtube. I'm trying to access the author name from the end of the description using jquery. To that, I've made this css selector `div[id="content"] > yt-formatted-string > a[href^="/channel"]` I've also made sure to trigger the "show more" button before using it in jquery.

This selector works perfectly fine in chrome's inspect tab, but in JQuery it returns an empty array. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Likely your element does not exist or is not accessible (cross frame) to your script at the time of execution

Comment: @mplungjan Yea that's what I thought too, looking for ways to deal with it right now.

Comment: @Teemu I'm pretty sure slashes are valid, but I still tried to escape it. Makes no difference.

Comment: Yeah change to href*=channel

Comment: @just_another_beginner Yup, I was wrong with that (partially), ex. in an id selector the slash must be escaped.

Comment: @mplungjan just tried it, still returns an empty array

Comment: Then it’s a timing or permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Update: Solved it.

Apparently, it was a timing solution. The code couldn't catch when the elements dynamically loaded, and instead looked too fast.

Fixed that with MutationObserver, and now it works perfectly.